# How to have the frontEnd and backEnd API on the same domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, vuejs2

I am developing a university project where I need to deploy the plataform, but I have a small problem.

Currently my website its working on my main domain https://www.example.com and the API its running on a subdomain https://api.example.com. So when I made calls from the frontEnd the calls are made to https://api.example.com/api/something, but what I want is to have it on the same domain, like https://www.example.com/api/somethin, and I dont know what I need to change to make it work.

My frontEnd its made with VueJS 2.0 and API with C# ASP.NET, my webserver its a windows server IIS 4.8.0, and my current web.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" 
            url="{MapProtocol:{HTTPS}}://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="MapProtocol">
              <add key="on" value="https" />
              <add key="off" value="http" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
    <tracing>
      <traceFailedRequests>
        <clear />
      </traceFailedRequests>
    </tracing>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation tempDirectory="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.com\tmp" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Can someone give me an ideia?

Thanks guys

Comment: I think Nginx can do it, in fact, I dont know what Nginx cant do =)

Comment: But my server its not an Nginx, and I dont know the configuration for IIS server

Comment: If your server is linux based you should be able to install Nginx, if not you can install docker and have a Nginx container.